# stacking order of multiple backgrounds including one using :before

Tags: html, css, svg

On this page https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/about/ I have a section (the second from last on the page) with three background images. The first two create the curved shape, the third is the pattern background. I then have a background logo using `:before` on the same set of classes to add a screened back logo.

```css
.et_pb_section.curves.yellow.texturebg.logobg {
background-image: 
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/whirlydots_top3.svg"), 
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/whirlydots_bottom.svg"),
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/circlebg-gold.jpg");
  background-size: 102%, 102%, cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: top center, bottom center, center center;
}

.et_pb_section.curves.yellow.texturebg.logobg::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url('https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/plush_logo.png') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position-x: right;
  opacity: 0.3; 
}
```

A few questions:

1. Is the only way to clip the `:before` logo to the curved background by adding a mask? You can hardly tell it is not being clipped bc it is so faint but I might want a tidier solution. The section below this one — the last section — is utilizing a `mask-image` on the row, which I sized to the section. It seems like a lot to add.
2. Alternately, is there an opacity rule I could use on a background image so they could be all in one stack (without using the `:before`)? I didn't find anything on this but maybe don't know the correct thing to search for.
3. Lastly (bonus): do I have to have absolute positioning on the logo? It seems to behave weirdly ie when I change the left and right it scales the logo instead of moving it. Putting the `background-position-x` allowed me to get it to float over there.

thanks.

```css
.et_pb_text_inner {
  position:relative;
  z-index:99999;
  font-family:'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  
}


.et_pb_section.curves {
  padding:60px 60px!important;
  background-image: 
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/whirlydots_top3.svg"), 
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/whirlydots_bottom.svg");
  background-size: 102%, 102%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: top center, bottom center;
  color:#444;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px  #efeae8;
}

.et_pb_section.curves.yellow.texturebg.logobg {
background-image: 
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/whirlydots_top3.svg"), 
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/whirlydots_bottom.svg"),
  url("https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/circlebg-gold.jpg");
  background-size: 102%, 102%, cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: top center, bottom center, center center;
}

.et_pb_section.curves.yellow.texturebg.logobg::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url('https://www.plushdesign.net/wp2023/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/plush_logo.png') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40%;
  background-position-x: right;
  opacity: 0.3; 
}
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_3 curves yellow texturebg logobg et_pb_with_background et_section_regular" >
  <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_5">
  <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_3  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
      <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
        <p>Santa came early, and I&#8217;m now the proud owner of a Ross-Tech Hex-V2, so I can run the real version of VCDS.  I had been running the shareware/Lite version, which has limited features.</p>
        <p>I&#8217;ve already verified the N80 is mechanically functional (both with manually applied 12V, as well as doing Sequential Output tests where I can hear the N80 clicking).  My carbon canister is brand new, and air flow through the evap purge line flows freely (when the N80 is open).   The van has no CEL or other DTCs.</p>
        <p>Is there any way to watch the N80 duty cycle in real time as I drive?  I have an oscilloscope so could tap into the electrical connector, but it would be neat to do it using VCDS measuring blocks.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to actually contain the code you want someone to look at.  In the future please just include your code in the question instead of linking to an external site like JSFiddle.